# how to find app features not being supported by current android version

Tags: android, webrtc, temasys

I am trying to make a sample screen sharing app using **Temasys sdk** which uses webrtc for screen sharing, they have actually targeted for **api level 29**. I developed the screen sharing app and its working preety good in android 9 but in android 10 when i try to start the screen sharing the local camera video is just paused but the screen sharing does not start.

What should actually happen is when i start the app then the first view i get is the frontcam video and hen when i should press the start screen share button then the frontcam video should pause there and on that screen the current screen should become visible,

but what is happening is that the frontcam video is pausing but the current screen is not visible on the main screen, its all happening in **android 10**, **upto android 9** its working good.

now i need to know what extra permissions i should add to it or what modifications should i add to it to make it working on android 10 also, where can i get all that unsupported features list.

**I tried logging into the logcat but it didnt helped.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to add mediaProjection in `AndroidManifest.xml`. Here is what I have done.

```
<service android:name="com.voximplant.foregroundservice.VIForegroundService" android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection|microphone|camera"></service>
```